# Difference between invoke and return function inside other function

Tags: javascript, function, return, invoke

I wonder what is the difference if I invoke a function **foo()** inside other function **bar()** or I return function **something()** inside function **test()**. What is the difference and which method is better to use?

```
var foo = function()
{
    console.log(2+3);
}

var bar = function()
{
    foo();
}
bar();

var test = function()
{
    var something = function()
    {
        console.log(5+7);
    }
    return something();
}
test();
```

Comment: In this particular example, the scope is pretty much the only difference. You cannot call `something` from outside of the `test` function. Yet, you can easily call `foo` from outside of the `bar` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't match what your prose says.

In both cases you invoke the function. In the second case you return the return value of it.

Since you don't do anything with the return value of the outer function, there is no practical difference in this case at all.

If you did do something with the return value, then the difference is that in the second case you would actually have a return value to do something with.

Answer (score 1):

Thank for answers but it's not exactly what i want to know.
What about this code:

```
    var foo = function()
    {
        var x = 2, y=3;
        return x+y;
    }

    var bar = function()
    {
        console.log(foo());
    }
    bar();

    ////        
    var test = function()
    {

        var something = function(a,b)
        {
            console.log(a*b);
        }
        return something(3,4);

    }
    test();

    ////
    var outer = function()
    {
        var inner = function(c,d)
        {
            return c-d;
        }
        console.log(inner(10,8));
    }
    outer();

    ////
    var outside = function()
    {
        var inside = function(e,f)
        {
            var divide = e/f;
            return divide;
        }
        var sum = inside(12,2) + 10;
        console.log(sum);           
    }
    outside();

    ////
    var access = function(age) {
            var limit = 8;
            return function(age, limit) {
                return age > limit;   
            }
    };
    console.log(access(50));
```

Last function **access()** is closest what i am about to. The whole thing makes me confused, because i watched course called "JavaScript. Understanding the weird parts". It's great, but i don't quite understand this functional programming where it's about transfering variables between other functions as well as return them from other functions. In that course, there is lesson where there are few functions, each returning something and next function takes it, doing something and returns other stuff.
I am about function **checkPastLimitSimplified()**. It takes arguments returned from other functions and return it's own function. How it works?

```
function mapForEach(arr, fn) {

    var newArr = [];
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newArr.push(
            fn(arr[i])   
        )
    };

    return newArr;
}

var arr1 = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr1);


var arr2 = mapForEach(arr1, function(item) {
   return item * 2; 
});
console.log(arr2);


var arr3 = mapForEach(arr1, function(item) {
   return item > 2; 
});
console.log(arr3);


var checkPastLimit = function(limiter, item) {
    return item > limiter;   
}
var arr4 = mapForEach(arr1, checkPastLimit.bind(this, 1));
console.log(arr4);


var checkPastLimitSimplified = function(limiter) {
    return function(limiter, item) {
        return item > limiter;   
    }.bind(this, limiter); 
};

var arr5 = mapForEach(arr1, checkPastLimitSimplified(1));
console.log(arr5);
```

And last thing, is there a good tutorial or book about functional programming which is used in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is not much of a difference, when invoking `foo` from `bar`, you don't return anything, you just invoke `foo` which will print `2 + 3` to console.

The second case where you return the result of invoking `something` you return `undefined` since it's also just a `console.log` statement you will return the result of said statement, but the `log` method returns `undefined` which is the value `test` will return.

A more common approach is to return a function, which can be invoked from there.
E.g.:

`var test = function()
{
    var something = function()
    {
        console.log(5+7);
    }
    return something;
}
var somethingFn = test();`

`test` will now return the function `something` which you can now invoke just like any other function:  `somethingFn()` -> prints 12

Answer (score 0):

Although what you expressed is different than what you wrote as a question is different let me try to answer for both cases. If the code is what you are trying to say: It is the accessibility difference. All `foo`, `bar` and `test` are accessible in this scope, but `something` is not. So you restricted `something` function to the function `test`. This is the only difference.

```
var foo = function()
{
    console.log(2+3);
}

var bar = function()
{
    foo();
}
bar(); // will print 5 to the console

var test = function()
{
    var something = function()
    {
        console.log(5+7);
    }
    return something(); // Assuming you return the return value of a function call (not the function itself)
}
test(); // will print 12 to the console
```

If what you wrote is what you are trying to ask: You return a function out of a call of a function.

```
var test = function()
{
    var something = function()
    {
        console.log(5+7);
    }
    return something; // this is a function that can be called later
}
var aFnToBeCalled = test();  // returns a function that is called. Nothing printed to the console yet.
aFnToBeCalled(); // prints 12 to the console.
```

Although it is not reflected in this example this is a good pattern to hide some information that gives a memory to the returned function. This is called `closure`:

```
var test = function()
{
    var numberOfTimesSomethingIsCalled = 0;
    var something = function()
    {
        ++numberOfTimesSomethingIsCalled; // numberOfTimesSomethingIsCalled is in the closure of something
        console.log(numberOfTimesSomethingIsCalled);
    }
    return something; // this is a function that can be called later
}

a = test();
b = test();

a(); // will print 1
a(); // will print 2
a(); // will print 3
b(); // will print 1
a(); // will print 4
```